# Can the BOSS RC-600 be the master MIDI sync to the RC-300?

Tags: looper-pedals

So up to this point, the BOSS RC-300 can't be the MIDI tempo sync slave of anything other than another RC-300.

Can the new BOSS RC-600 be the master MIDI sync to the RC-300?

Looking at the manual online, I'm afraid the answer may be "no," but the manual doesn't show the menu trees, so maybe?

I'd like to know before I buy one because I already have an RC-300 and I'm planning on live-looping with another musician who would use my old RC-300.

Comment: Roland is a very helpful company. Send them an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that RC-300 has a product-specific way of slaving that only works with another RC-300 or time spent analyzing MIDI messages and programming a MIDI pedal. So the answer is no. The RC-600 can slave to any MIDI device and doesn't have this problem.